# How to extract a table from .dat file while conserving its shape using python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a .dat file from Xcalibure (mass spec software) and I want to extract the table using Python.
I've tried sevral ways to achieve this but it always returns an 1D-shaped array with 100k rows and only 1 column.
I've linked my file and a picture of what the table must look like.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
data = csv.reader(r'file.dat', delimiter="\t")
data = open(r'file.dat')
data = np.loadtxt(r'file.dat', unpack = True)
data = np.fromfile(r'file.dat', dtype=float)
```

The .dat file is available [here](https://rapidgator.net/file/c06d730817308490e0c7703cc082da5d/file.dat.html).

[image]

Comment: Is the file binary? Text? Can you post a sample or a definition of the structure? None of your attempts make any sense because you don't have enough information.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a new 2 dimensional array and run a for loop for the number of rows and another nested for loop for the number of columns then put the data from there into the new 2d array

```
data = csv.reader(r'file.dat', delimiter="\t")
data = open(r'file.dat')
data = np.loadtxt(r'file.dat', unpack = True)
data = np.fromfile(r'file.dat', dtype=float)
dataTable[[]]
for y in range(number_of_rows):
     for x in range(number_of_columns):
          dataTable[y][x] = data[y*number_of_row+x]
```

this goes through each item in the list and based on the dimensions of the array, it will place the elements into arrays based on their row number.
this probably isnt the best way to extract this information into a 2d array but it works.